# Codeigniter : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on my View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got some error on my `View` form:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputJenis">Jenis Obat</label>
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></span>

       <select name="kode_jenis_obat" class="form-control" action="<?php echo form_dropdown('kode_jenis_obat',$hasil->kode_jenis_obat);?>">
           <option>Pilih Jenis Obat</option>
           <!-----Displaying fetched cities in options using foreach loop ---->
           <?php foreach ($kode_jenis_obat as $isi)
           {
                if($isi->kode_jenis_obat == $isi->kode_jenis_obat)
                {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $isi->kode_jenis_obat; ?>"><?php echo $isi->nama_jenisobat?></option>
                <?php}
                else 
                {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $isi->kode_jenis_obat; ?>"><?php echo $isi->nama_jenisobat?></option>
                <?php}
           }
           ?>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces in between `<?php` and `}`

so that you code will be :

```
<select name="kode_jenis_obat" class="form-control" action="<?php echo form_dropdown('kode_jenis_obat',$hasil->kode_jenis_obat);?>">
    <option>Pilih Jenis Obat</option>
    <!-----Displaying fetched cities in options using foreach loop ---->
    <?php foreach ($kode_jenis_obat as $isi)
    {
          if($isi->kode_jenis_obat == $isi->kode_jenis_obat)
          { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $isi->kode_jenis_obat; ?>"><?php echo $isi->nama_jenisobat?></option>
      <?php } else {?>
             <option value="<?php echo $isi->kode_jenis_obat; ?>"><?php echo $isi->nama_jenisobat?></option>
      <?php } } ?>
</select>
```